# how to automatically create table based on CSV into postgres using python

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, python-import

I am a new Python programmer and trying to import a sample CSV file into my Postgres database using python script.
I have CSV file with name abstable1 it has 3 headers:

> absid, name, number
> I have many such files in a folder
> I want to create a table into PostgreSQL with the same name as the CSV file for all.

Here is the code which I tried to just create a table for one file to test:

```
import psycopg2
import csv
import os

#filePath = 'c:\\Python27\\Scripts\\abstable1.csv'
conn = psycopg2.connect("host= hostnamexx dbname=dbnamexx user= usernamexx password= pwdxx")
print("Connecting to Database")
cur = conn.cursor()

#Uncomment to execute the code below to create a table
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE abs.abstable1(
absid varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
name integer,
number integer 
)
 """)
#to copy the csv data into created table
with open('abstable1.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    cur.copy_from(f, 'abs.abstable1', sep=',')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
File "c:\Python27\Scripts\testabs.py", line 26, in <module>
    cur.copy_from(f, 'abs.abstable1', sep=',')
psycopg2.errors.QueryCanceled: COPY from stdin failed: error in .read() call: exceptions.ValueError Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
CONTEXT:  COPY abstable1, line 1
```

Any recommendation or alternate solution to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what worked for me by: `import glob`

This code automatically reads **all CSV files in a folder and Creates a table with Same name as of the file.**
Although I'm still trying to figure out how to extract specific datatypes according to the data in CSV.
But as far as table creation is concerned, this works like a charm for all CSV files in a folder.

```
import csv
import psycopg2
import os
import glob


conn = psycopg2.connect("host= hostnamexx dbname=dbnamexx user= usernamexx password= 
pwdxx")
print("Connecting to Database")

csvPath = "./TestDataLGA/"

# Loop through each CSV
for filename in glob.glob(csvPath+"*.csv"):
# Create a table name
tablename = filename.replace("./TestDataLGA\\", "").replace(".csv", "")
print tablename

# Open file
fileInput = open(filename, "r")

# Extract first line of file
firstLine = fileInput.readline().strip()


# Split columns into an array [...]
columns = firstLine.split(",")
     

# Build SQL code to drop table if exists and create table
sqlQueryCreate = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '+ tablename + ";\n"
sqlQueryCreate += 'CREATE TABLE'+ tablename + "("

#some loop or function according to your requiremennt
# Define columns for table
for column in columns:
    sqlQueryCreate += column + " VARCHAR(64),\n"

sqlQueryCreate = sqlQueryCreate[:-2]
sqlQueryCreate += ");"

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sqlQueryCreate)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code and works fine

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("host= 127.0.0.1 dbname=testdb user=postgres password=postgres")
print("Connecting to Database")
cur = conn.cursor()

'''cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE abstable1(
absid varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
name integer,
number integer 
)
""")'''

with open('lolo.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    cur.copy_from(f, 'abstable1', sep=',', columns=('absid', 'name', 'number'))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

although i had to make some changes for it to work:
i had to name the table **abstable1** because using **abs.abstable1** postgres assumes that i'm using the schema **abs**, maybe you created that schema on your database if not check on that, also i'm using python 3.7
i noticed that you are using python 2.7(which i think is no longer supported), this  may cause issues, since you say you are learning i would recommend that you use python 3 since it is more used now and you most likely encounter code written on it and you would have to be adapting your code to fit your python 2.7

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I changed the csv name as well.

Answer (score 0):

I post my solution here based on @Rose answer.

I used sqlalchemy, a JSON file as config and glob.

```
import json
import glob
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text


def create_tables_from_files(files_folder, engine, config):
    try:
        for filename in glob.glob(files_folder+"\*csv"):
            tablename = filename.replace(files_folder, "").replace('\\', "").replace(".csv", "")
            input_file = open(filename, "r")
            columns = input_file.readline().strip().split(",")
            create_query = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + config["staging_schema"] + "." + tablename + "; \n"
            create_query +='CREATE TABLE ' + config["staging_schema"] + "." + tablename + " ( "

            for column in columns:
                create_query += column + " VARCHAR, \n "

            create_query = create_query[:-4]
            create_query += ");"

            engine.execute(text(create_query).execution_options(autocommit=True))
            print(tablename + " table created")
    except:
        print("Error at uploading tables")
```