# How to automatically create table and its columns based on CSV using python

Tags: python, csv, automation, python-import, sqldatatypes

This is the snippet for CSV

```
Column Header                   Values
LGA_CODE_2016                   LGA10050    
Median_age_persons              39  
Median_mortgage_repay_monthly   1421    
Median_tot_prsnl_inc_weekly     642 
Median_rent_weekly              231 
Median_tot_fam_inc_weekly       1532    
Average_num_psns_per_bedroom    0.8 
Median_tot_hhd_inc_weekly       1185    
Average_household_size          2.3
```

I have 200+ CSVs which has combination of datatypes such as **Varchar, Integer, Float**.
First column of every table **must** be Primary Key. (i.e LGA_CODE_2016 as above mentioned CSV)

Here is the code I tried

```
import csv
import psycopg2
import os
import glob
import re

conn = psycopg2.connect("host= hostnamexx dbname=dbnamexx user= usernamexx password= 
pwdxx")
print("Connecting to Database")

csvPath = "./TestDataLGA/"

# Loop through each CSV
for filename in glob.glob(csvPath+"*.csv"):
    # Create a table name
    tablename = filename.replace("./TestDataLGA\\", "").replace(".csv", "")
    print tablename

    # Open file
    fileInput = open(filename, "r")

    # Extract first line of file
    firstLine = fileInput.readline().strip()

    #Extract seconf line of file
    secondLine = fileInput.readline()

    # Split columns into an array [...]
    columns = firstLine.split(",")
    colvals = secondLine.split(",")
     

    # Build SQL code to drop table if exists and create table
    sqlQueryCreate = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '+ " abs.ABS_" + tablename + ";\n"
    sqlQueryCreate += 'CREATE TABLE'+ " abs.ABS_" + tablename + "("

    # Define columns for table
    for column in columns:
        for dtype in colvals:
            dt = bool(re.match(r"^\d+?\.\d+?$", dtype))   
            if dtype.isdigit():
                dtype = "INTEGER"
                 
            elif dt == True:
                dtype = "FLOAT(2)"
                
            else:
                dtype = "VARCHAR(64)"
                
                
        sqlQueryCreate += column + " " + dtype + ",\n"
            
        
    sqlQueryCreate = sqlQueryCreate[:-2]
    sqlQueryCreate += ");"
    
    print sqlQueryCreate

    #cur = conn.cursor()
    #cur.execute(sqlQueryCreate)
    #conn.commit()
    #cur.close()
```

This is the output that I am getting

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  abs.ABS_G02_AUS_LGA;
CREATE TABLE abs.ABS_G02_AUS_LGA(LGA_CODE_2016 FLOAT(2),
Median_age_persons FLOAT(2),
Median_mortgage_repay_monthly FLOAT(2),
Median_tot_prsnl_inc_weekly FLOAT(2),
Median_rent_weekly FLOAT(2),
Median_tot_fam_inc_weekly FLOAT(2),
Average_num_psns_per_bedroom FLOAT(2),
Median_tot_hhd_inc_weekly FLOAT(2),
Average_household_size FLOAT(2));
PS C:\Python27\Scripts>
```

If I run my inner **For* loop* by itself I get correct set of Datatypes based on the CSV but when I am trying to run it with other **For* loop*, it only prints the last generated datatype which is Float(2) for all column headers.
I am also confused where to put code for Primary Key.

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

I have tried several permutations and combination of looping them and using **Break** command. But nothing seems to work.

PS: I am working on Test data hence just one CSV file can be seen here output.
This is the continuation for my earlier question [how to automatically create table based on CSV into postgres using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887333/how-to-automatically-create-table-based-on-csv-into-postgres-using-python/63126520#63126520)

Comment: Did you try pandas?

Comment: @Peaceful No, I am not much aware of Pandas. I am fairly new to Python. I want to continue with this as I sort of have started to understand it unless Pandas would fix this straightaway.

Comment: if you get only last item then you probably have wrong indentation and you run some code outside loop but you should run it inside loop.

Comment: first you should use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called "print debuging".